# R Studio/Sweave: My Compiler is Possessed by Satan

Tags: r

My Sweave compiler is possessed: I get these bizarre significance levels for linear regression summary on the pdf doc generated:

```
<<echo=TRUE>>=
heart.bank <- lm(ex0914$Heart~ex0914$Bank)
heart.walk <- lm(ex0914$Heart~ex0914$Walk)
heart.talk <- lm(ex0914$Heart~ex0914$Talk)
summary(heart.bank)
summary(heart.walk)
summary(heart.talk)
res.bank <- resid(heart.bank)
res.walk <- resid(heart.walk)
res.talk <- resid(heart.talk)
fit.bank <- predict(heart.bank,data.frame(ex0914$Bank))
fit.walk <- predict(heart.walk,data.frame(ex0914$Walk))  
fit.talk <- predict(heart.talk,data.frame(ex0914$Talk))
@
```

resulting in

^ ̆A ̈Y***a^ ̆A ́Z

for the Signif Codes: section of the linear model summary() calls.

What is the deal R Studio?

Comment: try `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (in your Sweave file) or `options(useFancyQuotes=FALSE)` or `options(useFancyQuotes="TeX")` in your R code.

Comment: the first option worked! thanks ben

Answer (score 3):

(Upgraded from a comment.)

This happens because R uses fancy (non-ASCII) quotation marks in the coefficient table output by default. Try

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

(in your Sweave file) or

```
options(useFancyQuotes=FALSE)
```

or

```
 options(useFancyQuotes="TeX")
```

in your R code.